# Web Form Next Number Generation Scenario

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a web form with several fields first field is Employee Number which is having "EMP - 0001" Format.i'm generating next Employee number by considering the last Emp Number added and converting the latter part to integer and add one

ex: split EMP - 0001 -> get 0001 -> convert it to integer -> add one -> generate next no as EMP - 0002

Next Employee Number should be visible to the user.my issue is when there are multiple users using the system.imagine that one user opens the web Form and doesn't save the record.his Employee Number is EMP - 0002.another user opens the web form he also sees the EMP no as 0002 because last record is not saved yet.2nd user saves the records he gets the Number 0002.1st user then saves the record.so at last i've got duplicate EMP Numbers in my database.what kind of scenario should i follow to over come this situation

Comment: You could switch from int to GUID's

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accurately predict their ID is to put in a blank record, get the ID used, then when they enter the form, update the record with their information. However, if they quit the form, you're left with a blank record.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the record on the DB and get the ID it returns. You won't have concurrency issues there if you're opening and disclosing your connection correctly.

Comment: can u explain "opening and disclosing your connection correctly" a bit..Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is prone to concurrency issues as you pointed out & I will not recommend it you. You have the following options.

1. Use an `Identity` column in your database table as a serial column (The database automatically increments the identity column on every insert row operation- you don't have to specify it through code)[SQL Server Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
2. Use a `database sequence` (Depeding on your database version & its support - A database sequence returns a unique integer value - this can also be cached, presented on form once the form loads - once generated, same sequence is never generated again)
3. Use a `database trigger` to automatically update the Id column on every row insert

Depeding on your requirement, you can pick one option.

Answer (score 0):

After saving the record you can give the user message tah record is saved and your Employee numnber is "EMP - 0002".